# How to show that if $G/N$ and $N$ soluble then so is $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group, solvable-groups

I am trying to show that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ that is soluble and $G/N$ is soluble then so is $G$.

I am wondering whether it has something to do with the isomorphism theorem for groups. But I can’t think of how to do it.

Comment: Hint: What does it mean for a group to be soluble? Knowing that $N$ is soluble lends itself to showing that G must also be soluble (why?).

Comment: $N$ and $G/N$ have normal sequences with abelian quotient groups. Now use the correspondence theorem to "continue" the sequence of $N$ with the sequence of $G/N$.